# c# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required

Tags: c#, email

I am trying to send an email using C# using the following function:

```
public static void SendEmail(string fromAddress, string password)
        {
            SmtpClient email = new SmtpClient
            {
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                EnableSsl = true,
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, password)
            };
            string subject = "Mail subject";
            string body = "Body";

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sending email...");
                email.Send(fromAddress, GetToAddress(), subject, body);
            } catch (SmtpException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

I see that in order for it to work, I need to enable less secure apps on my gmail account. However, according to google "To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.
". Is there any other way to send a mail?

Comment: did ur issue is sort? if yes please accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can enable two-factor authentication on the google account and then create an apps password

[How to create app password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en)

This will generate 16-character "App password". Then take the exact same code you used before and replace the standard user Gmail password with the apps password.

ex:

```
SendEmail("Nave@gmail.com", "iodwsurnuyjfsxdc") // here iodwsurnuyjfsxdc means app password and Nave@gmail.com means app pass generated account email
```